# Migrate Mariadb 10.3 to Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mariadb, migration

What is failsafe way to migrate ?
Both database are on CentOS 7 different servers and latest versions of database.

Comment: Firstly backup your DB structure (everything except data) on MariaDB using `mysqlbackup` and then try to restore it on MySQL. It will show does some specific for MariaDB options are present, and if so, you must investigate does it is possible to adapt the backup for to import onto MySQL. If you find success way then do the same but with DB data (or backup data only and import it into previously imported structure).

Comment: I will update here once I attempt this in off hours.

Comment: Use the source's (ie, MariaDB's) `mysqldump`.  That will _probably_ avoid incompatibilities in the dump file.  In the other direction, the keyword `VISIBLE` has tripped up a number of DBAs.